# How can I access <tomcat>\bin\*.properties when running from inside eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration, classpath

Does anyone know if Tomcat running inside of Eclipse truly uses the `<tomcat>\bin\` directory when you've configured your server to use your local Tomcat install (Server view) inside Eclipse?

For example: I'm using a colleagues jar, which subsequently requires the ***X.properties*** file.  I've been instructed to place that properties file in the `<tomcat>\bin\` directory.  This is sort of odd to me, but the line that fails is simply:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("X.properties");
```

Anyhow, I'm pretty sure [editing any of the Server config](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_can_I_view_or_modify_the_launch_configuration_properties_for_a_Tomcat_server.3F) files will not help me, though I'm open to any suggestions.  Or perhaps there's something in my launch configuration (below) that I can change?

[image]

**No matter what, I get the following stack trace:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: X.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at com.mycompany.myteam.colleaguesproject.colleaguesservlet.init(colleaguesservlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java designates the directory that you started it from as its 'working directory', and any relative paths are relative to that directory.  In this case, that's Tomcat's bin directory, which contains Tomcat's startup script.

You should put the properties file in C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\bin to make this work, though this is not a good practice for java properties files.  Reading them in off of Java's classpath is standard, and much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help on this, your answer combined with @Ratna Dinakar (below) absolutely helped me out :)  It's much appreciated.  Of course, solving one problem leads to the next...

Why is it that my CLASSPATH when running outside of eclipse will contain things like X.properties (per the environment variable) , but inside eclipse, X.properties is not read from the CLASSPATH environment variable?

Comment: Eclipse manages the classpath of anything it's running separately, as does just about any IDE.  Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to have different classpaths for different projects.  Decent instructions on how to manage the classpath in Eclipse can be found here - http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html

Comment: thanks again.  I'll have to read the article.  I also wanted to post an update:

Essentially placing the properties file that my co-worker's code expected -  in <tomcat>\bin\ - in my Eclipse root folder , I was able to leverage my co-workers jars, that were using the file.  The reason this worked, was that the co-workers code expected the file to be in the same directory Java was "started in", so in dev & qa that's <tomcat>\bin\ , but on my local machine that's the Eclipse root folder.

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with mblinn !

Eclipse creates a local instance of tomcat server, for which eclipse.exe is the Main application.

Try placing your X.properties file in eclipse root folder.